# Count the reocurrence of words in text file

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Expanding on my a previous exercise, I have a text file that is filled with one word per line.

```
hello
hi
hello
bonjour
bonjour
hello
```

As I read these words from the file I would like to compare them to an array of struct pointers (created from the text file). If the word does not exist within the array, the word should be stored into a struct pointer with a count of 1. If the word already exist in the array the count should increase by 1. I will write the outcome into a new file (that already exist).

```
hello = 3
hi = 1
bonjour = 2
```

this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct wordfreq{
    int count;
    char *word;
};
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    struct wordfreq *words[1000] = {NULL};
    int i, j, f = 0;
    for(i=0; i <1000; i++)
        words[i] = (struct wordfreq*)malloc(sizeof(struct wordfreq));

    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE *output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if(input == NULL){
        printf("Error! Can't open file.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    char str[20];
    i=0;
    while(fscanf(input, "%s[^\n]", &str) ==1){
        //fprintf(output, "%s:\n", str);
        for(j=0; j<i; j++){
            //fprintf(output, "\t%s  == %s\n", str, words[j] -> word);
            if(str == words[j]->word){
                words[j] ->count ++;
                f = 1;
            }
        }
        if(f==0){
            words[i]->word = str;
            words[i]->count = 1;
        }
        //fprintf(output, "\t%s = %d\n", words[i]->word, words[i]->count);
        i++;
    }

    for(j=0; j< i; j++)
        fprintf(output, "%s = %d\n", words[j]->word, words[j]->count);
    for(i=0; i<1000; i++){
        free(words[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I used several fprintf statements to look at my values and I can see that while str is right, when I reach the line to compare str to the other array struct pointers `(str == words[I]->word)` during the transversal `words[0] -> word` is always the same as str and the rest of the `words[i]->words` are (null). I am still trying to completely understand mixing pointes and structs, with that said any thoughts, comments, complains?

Comment: `==` is not the right way to compare strings in C. Use [`strcmp`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp)

Comment: `words[i]->word = str`. That is wrong because it makes all the words point to the *same* `str` buffer. Use `words[i]->word = strdup(str)` to make a copy of the string. Don't forget to free that memory when it is no longer needed as `strdup` returns dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: `while(fscanf(input, "%s[^\n]", &str) ==1)`  isn't correct. `str` is a character array. The array name itself gives the base address of that array. `while(fscanf(input, "%s[^\n]", str) ==1)` will do.

Comment: I don't think you will need that `[^\n]` in `while(fscanf(input, "%s[^\n]"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be making things a bit harder than necessary, and you are certainly allocating `997` more structures than necessary in the case of your input file. There is no need to allocate all `1000` structs up front. (you are free to do so, it's just a memory management issue). The key is that you only need allocate a new struct each time a unique word is encountered. (in the case of your data file, 3-times). For all other cases, you are simply updating `count` to add the occurrence for a word you have already stored.

Also, if there is no compelling reason to use a `struct`, it is just as easy to use an array of *pointers-to-char* as your pointers to each `word`, and then a simple array of `int [1000]` as your `count` (or frequency) array. Your choice. In the case of two arrays, you only need to allocate for each unique `word` and never need a separate allocation for each `struct`.

Putting those pieces together, you could reduce your code (not including the file -- which can be handled by simple *redirection*) to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXC = 128, MAXW = 1000 };

struct wordfreq{
    int count;
    char *word;
};

int main (void) {

    struct wordfreq *words[MAXW] = {0};
    char tmp[MAXC] = "";
    int n = 0;

    /* while < MAXW unique words, read each word in file */
    while (n < MAXW && fscanf (stdin, " %s", tmp) == 1) {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)         /* check against exising words */
            if (strcmp (words[i]->word, tmp) == 0)  /* if exists, break */
                break;

        if (i < n) {            /* if exists */
            words[i]->count++;  /* update frequency */
            continue;           /* get next word */
        }

        /* new word found, allocate struct and
         * allocate storage for word (+ space for nul-byte) 
         */
        words[n] = malloc (sizeof *words[n]);
        words[n]->word = malloc (strlen (tmp) + 1);
        if (!words[n] || !words[n]->word) { /* validate ALL allocations */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: memory exhausted, words[%d].\n", n);
            break;
        }
        words[n]->count = 0;    /* initialize count */

        strcpy (words[n]->word, tmp); /* copy new word to words[n] */
        words[n]->count++;            /* update frequency to 1 */
        n++;                          /* increment word count */
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { /* for each word */
        printf ("%s = %d\n", words[i]->word, words[i]->count);
        free (words[i]->word);    /* free memory when no longer needed */
        free (words[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/wordfile.txt
hello
hi
hello
bonjour
bonjour
hello
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/filewordfreq <dat/wordfile.txt
hello = 3
hi = 1
bonjour = 2
```

As with any code that dynamically allocates memory, you will want to **validate** your use of the memory to insure you have not written beyond the bounds or based a conditional move or jump on an uninitialized value. In Linux, `valgrind` is the natural choice (there are similar programs for each OS). Just run you program through it, e.g.:

```
$ valgrind ./bin/filewordfreqstruct <dat/wordfile.txt
==2000== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2000== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2000== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2000== Command: ./bin/filewordfreqstruct
==2000==
hello = 3
hi = 1
bonjour = 2
==2000==
==2000== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2000==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2000==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 65 bytes allocated
==2000==
==2000== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2000==
==2000== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2000== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Verify that you `free` all memory you allocate and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

---

**Using 2-Arrays Instead of a** `struct`

As mentioned above, sometimes using a *storage array* and a *frequency array* can simplify accomplishing the same thing. Whenever you are faced with needing the frequency of any "set", your first thought should be a *frequency array*. It is nothing more than an array of the same size as the number of items in your "set", (initialized to `0` at the beginning). The same approach applies, when you add (or find a duplicate of an existing) element in your *storage array*, you increment the corresponding element in your *frequency array* by `1`. When you are done, your *frequency array elements* hold the frequency the corresponding elements in your *storage array* appear.

Here is an equivalent to the program above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXC = 128, MAXW = 1000 };

int main (void) {

    char *words[MAXW] = {NULL},   /* storage array of pointers to char* */
        tmp[MAXC] = "";
    int freq[MAXW] = {0}, n = 0;  /* simple integer frequency array */

    /* while < MAXW unique words, read each word in file */
    while (n < MAXW && fscanf (stdin, " %s", tmp) == 1) {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; words[i]; i++)   /* check against exising words */
            if (strcmp (words[i], tmp) == 0)    /* if exists, break */
                break;

        if (words[i]) {     /* if exists */
            freq[i]++;      /* update frequency */
            continue;       /* get next word */
        }

        /* new word found, allocate storage (+ space for nul-byte) */
        words[n] = malloc (strlen (tmp) + 1);
        if (!words[n]) {    /* validate ALL allocations */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: memory exhausted, words[%d].\n", n);
            break;
        }

        strcpy (words[n], tmp); /* copy new word to words[n] */
        freq[n]++;              /* update frequency to 1 */
        n++;                    /* increment word count */
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {                 /* for each word */
        printf ("%s = %d\n", words[i], freq[i]);  /* output word + freq */
        free (words[i]);           /* free memory when no longer needed */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Using this approach, you eliminate 1/2 of your memory allocations by using a statically declared *frequency array* for your `count`. Either way is fine, it is largely up to you.

Comment: I seem to be getting a "invalid read of size 8" during valgrind that results in    a segmentation fault.

Comment: Never mind, i seem to have found the problem. The comments really helped me understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Good, glad I could help you along. The "invalid read of size 8" generally means you are trying to read 1 pointer after the last bit of valid data (which usually means your loop index is off by `1` `:)`

Comment: For the learning benefit, I'll also post the simpler solution that uses 2-arrays instead of a struct. Sometimes the KISS philosophy really helps.