# dynamic memory reading from a file

Tags: c, memory-management, struct

I desperately need some help with an exercise my professor gave me. Essentially, I'm making a program using a structure and dynamic memory where it'll read a file where each line has one word, and it'll print to a new file each unique word and how many times it was in the file.

So for instance, if the file going in had this

```
apple
orange
orange
```

The file it prints to would say

```
apple 1
orange 2
```

So far, this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct wordfreq {
int count;
char *word;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int i;
char *temp;
FILE *from, *to;
from = fopen("argc[1]","r");
to = fopen("argv[1]","w");

struct wordfreq w1[1000];
struct wordfreq *w1ptr[1000];
for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    w1ptr[i] = NULL;
for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    w1ptr[i] = (struct wordfreq*)malloc(sizeof(struct wordfreq));

while(fscanf(from,"%256s",temp)>0){

}

for(i = 999; i >= 0; i--)
    free(w1ptr[i]);

}
```

w1ptr should store a word from the file in the wordfreq file, then increment count in that array. I have no clue how to go about storing the word in *word though. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You have to allocate memory for `char *temp;` before you use it in `fscanf`

Comment: 1) `int main(){` --> `int main(int argc, char *argv[]){`, `from = fopen("argc[1]","r");
to = fopen("argv[1]","w");` --> `from = fopen(argv[1], "r"); to = fopen(argv[2], "w");`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY he first has to redefine man before that is `main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: You may find [**Count the reocurrence of words in text file**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43444995/count-the-reocurrence-of-words-in-text-file/43445812#43445812) helpful.

Answer (score -1):

This is how in general your read/write from a file

```
const int maxString = 1024; // put this before the main

    const char * fn = "test.file";          // file name
    const char * str = "This is a literal C-string.\n";

    // create/write the file
    puts("writing file\n");
    FILE * fw = fopen(fn, "w");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        fputs(str, fw);
    }

    fclose(fw);
    puts("done.");

    // read the file
    printf("reading file\n");
    char buf[maxString];
    FILE * fr = fopen(fn, "r");
    while(fgets(buf, maxString, fr)) {
        fputs(buf, stdout);
    }

    fclose(fr);
    remove(fn); // to delete a file

    puts("done.\n");
```